# Vue Draggable with touch - drop doesn't trigger

Tags: vue.js

I have been working on a website that has to function on both desktop and tablets. Part of the website is having three columns and being able to drag orders from column to column. Sometimes on drop, the user has to answer a few questions or change some of the data of that specific order. This happens in a pop-up window that is triggered by an @drop function (for example @drop="approved()". The method approved() then checks the status of the dropped order and shows the pop-up window).

When I am on desktop, everything works just fine. But when I switch to iPad Pro in the developer tools, nothing happens. I implemented Vue Draggable, which says to work with touch devices. In their examples I can't find anything about touch events or adding new handles for touch, so I don't know what to do now. 
The dragging works just fine with touch devices, it's just the @drop function that doesn't trigger.

The dropzone (it includes a component that contains the draggables and a lot of if-statements):

```
<div class="col-md-4 border" @dragover.prevent @drop="approved()">
  <Wachtrij class="fullHeight" :data2="opdrachtenData2"></Wachtrij>
</div>
```

The method:

```
export default {
 methods: {
  ...
  approved() {
   console.log("Function approved() is being executed.")
   if (this.draggingOrder.status === 5) {
    this.popupGekeurd = true;
   }
   else if (this.draggingOrder.status === 6) {
    this.popupTochGoed = true;
   }
   else if ([40, 52, 42,41,49,55,54].indexOf(this.draggingOrder.status) !== -1) {
    this.back = true;
   }
  },
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the code.

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried testing it with an actual touch device to see if the problem appears there too? It may be just a devtool bug. Otherwise it may be an issue with it not detecting the div as a valid drop target, but I am unsure why it would only be an issue on touch devices. I would expect your dragover event from being prevented even with touch. You could inspect the `target` attribute on the `dragend` event on a draggable element to see where it thinks it ended the drag.

Comment: Touch device doesn't work. I tried testing in Firefox as well, didn't work. `target`, `from` and `to` on `@dragend` are the div I am currently dragging and not the dropzone. I'm at a loss :(
- update: Safari seems to be the only browser where @drop works with touch devices. Whyyyyy????????????!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using native events, while the touch implementation does not (always?) use these events. It is intended that you use a `draggable` component with [one of the events outlined in the documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events). In your case the `start` and `end` events look promising. This event has a few properties ([docs](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#event-object-demo)), some of them being `to` and `from`.

Let's assume that we have the following code:

```
<draggable v-for="(zone, index) in zones" v-model="zones[index]" :class="['dropzone', `zone-${index}`]" :key="`dropzone-${index}`" :options="options" @start="start" @end="end">
  <div v-for="item in zones[index]" class="dropitem" :key="`dropitem-${item.id}`">
    {{ item.title }}
  </div>
</draggable>
```

This creates a few zones, each filled with their own items. Each array item of `zones` is changed based on where you move each item. You can then use `start` to have information on when you start moving an item, and `end` to have information on when you stop moving an item, and where that item came from and where it ended up. The following methods show off what you can do with that in this case:

```
  methods: {
    start (event) {
      console.log('start', event);
    },

    end (event) {
      console.log('end', event);

      const { from, to } = event;
      if (to.className.match(/\bzone-2\b/)) {
        console.log('Zone 2 has something added!')
      }
      if (from.className.match(/\bzone-0\b/)) {
        console.log('Zone 0 had something removed!');
      }
    }
  }
```

We make our dropzones with a class `zone-0`, `zone-1` or `zone-2` in this case, so we can use the class name to determine which dropzone we ended up in.

---

An alternative way to determine which zone was changed is to simply use a watcher. Since `zones` changes based on where you move items, you can simply watch a particular dropzone for changes and do things based on that.

```
  watch: {
    'zones.1': {
      handler (oldZone, newZone) {
        if (Array.isArray(oldZone) && Array.isArray(newZone) && oldZone.length !== newZone.length) {
          console.log('Zone 1 was changed from', oldZone, 'to', newZone);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

A full example can be found on codesandbox.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The `to` and `from` of the `start` and `end` events are always the same: the id of the element I am currently dragging and dropping, but never the intended dropzone. Your code works, though. I am trying to move the draggable around, to see if that changes something to the `event`.

Comment: I finally got it working by removing the component that held the draggables ("Wachtrij" in the code of my question). With placing the draggables directly in the container, everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I found this thread but I did not fet the answer, also demo is not working. Could you tell what was the last solution you have implemented?